# Detecting a final Url after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, httpwebrequest

I tried to detect the final Url after a redirect. The Url is shown below. When using chrome I receive the 302 response however in my code I simply see a 200 without an Url change. I'm able to see 302 status using chrome dev tools.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQf6I.jpg (Chrome console image at this link)

I've tested with another Url which works. I've noticed the latency for the tiny url is 1.21 s and for the other Url is 85 ms. Maybe the Redirect is so fast it doesn't get noticed?

I've included my code at the bottom.

References used trying to detect the redirect:

[Getting the Redirected URL from the Original URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704956/getting-the-redirected-url-from-the-original-url)

[Get a collection of redirected URLs from HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990604/get-a-collection-of-redirected-urls-from-httpwebresponse)

Works: http://tinyurl.com/qcrr3kn

Not working: http://api.citygridmedia.com/content/places/v2/click?q=urVBa6moXC5c7fD6SHv-hbf_7HRTJ-epI2pHQq9_3jGRS3oxUEA3zsS1yLhsh9JEMiM8qdYEtS_lStDSZc-z0HmZe5l2XwN1a5djnuXu5V1qx7Z8EcA6yxLKrMog1OH9vFD9461355g648hyYiUbBiYsgkiDMf0VK0OyE5NeCh7xaY-OWE-pI6J9TXcyr1kJ5B5hTzbOJpxvXVdX05ZCdwHpYplILuELic5q1ojeI1nhJzk8Tl7wsl-lPrROPRwrv6Vvvc3wVE2idwR784UoxXgZt00XiBh6rVYpGf0-q80smzQZRNmEcO7wa3342DmMbLPlCUd6QMCCSyvMlmgc4Q7yPuDG5vGRdaSPzm47_mTd74r6ovP00DvY5ODHN3LETLY7LMYirpiUus0hR1WWmUC26M-JCspa2l7J14e2WcsVUHKek47lJyLmPoAqUFoLFNwKZyOqQKk

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36";

request.Method = "GET";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

string myTestUri = request.RequestUri.ToString();

string testResponse = null;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = null;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(response.CharacterSet) == true)
readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
else
readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
output = readStream.ReadToEnd();
string newUrl = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;//  api.citygridmedia.com domain is returned

string uriString = response.GetResponseHeader("Location"); //  empty for the api.citygridmedia.com domain
```

Comment: Update: If I use a process and then grab the browser window after going to that url but this is too computationally heavy of an option for me to use. Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: I *very* much doubt that the speed of the redirect has anything to do with it.

Comment: hmm. Then why doesn't the response contain the redirect? Do you think its differentiating my server's get request from that of a browser somehow ? (reading headers etc)

Comment: No idea, but I doubt that speed has anything to do with it.

Comment: You have any suggestions i might try out ? I'm stuck

Comment: I suggest you look at the network traffic with Wireshark to start with.

Comment: thanks I'm trying that out

Comment: so it turns out they were sending a 200 no 302. But when I set one of the accepted encoding as an image I got the redirect. and boom off to the races. I'm still unsure exactly how that works..but I shall see.